# controlling the motors of the CD/DVD drive

Tags: winapi, hardware, firmware, scsi

The DVD drive of my laptop is not functional altough Windows says that the driver is correctly installed.Indeed,I checked the behavior of the motors : the sledge motor is stuck on the same position (not translating) while the turn-table motor seems to be turning when inserting a CD/DVD (I can hear its sound for a lapse of time)...

As an old PlayStation player I know that this is a bad sign...My guess is that something is blocking the sledge motor...

I thought for a while that I could control programmatically the motors ( to check them) through the SCSI commands but I realized later that this interface does not offer such capabilities .Since motors and their position calculation may be even a matter of firmware and chip-sets,my next move now is to search for a more low level API - why not assembly language - to find a solution but I'm clueless and can't find documentation for such functionalities...

**Did I miss something regarding the SCSI documentation or is there an existing API to control the CD drive motors ?**

Comment: Not at the user level. Even at the kernel level it seems like it's manufacturer-dependent.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't exposed via WINAPI anywhere. You might be able to test this using DOS and a CDROM driver that exposes the legacy disk API.

Comment: You may find a manufacturer-specific code via [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) though.

Comment: so ,no high level API can do it ?

Comment: I'd just investigate getting the drive replaced. Or just forget about it and move on from physical media :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no WinAPI can achieve this.(Maybe in future)
Make sure that your CD/DVD is okay (whether the CD/DVD is corrupted, format is not supported, region restrictions).

Of course you can get the device status with `DeviceIoControl` and [`IOCTL_CDROM_CHECK_VERIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddcdrm/ni-ntddcdrm-ioctl_cdrom_check_verify)(this IOCTL is replaced by [`IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddstor/ni-ntddstor-ioctl_storage_check_verify) according to the doc). You can find an example of how to retrieve it on [Larry Osterman's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/05/02/playing-audio-cds-part-7-dae-table-of-contents/).

Or you can try to use the [`mciSendString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757161(v%3Dvs.85)) with [Multimedia Command Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Multimedia/multimedia-command-strings)(such 
 as [play](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/Multimedia/play),[step](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/Multimedia/step)...).

Maybe all you need to do is dust your hardware.